# Free object movement keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, graphics, objects

In many graphic and writing tools there snapping grids and other constraints which block the user to move graphic objects to unwanted positions or to help aligning objects to other objects.

In Linux (as I remember correctly) it's common to use the ALT key on the keyboard to allow the user to disable those features and enter the "free object movement" mode spontaneously while pressed.

**What is the best key for such feature in a standard 2D graphics editor for Mac, Windows and Linux?**

Comment: Does your application use any other keyboard shortcuts or keys? If yes, please list them. This will be something a user gets by trial and surprise/error. Making similar results similar to achieve will help with this.

Comment: The best key is the one that people already associate with that behavior. So I'd look at popular apps in those OS's to see what they use.

Comment: Voting to keep this open since it doesn't seem to be about implementation. The question is about what key should modify users' actions.